# MeteorJS Tasks.find() by <select> dropdown?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my to-do-app I have a **static** `<select>` dropdown list, which I like to use to find specific tasks from the database. But how to get it working? I wired up an event and tried to set a variable `assortment` but it seems the template doesn't get re-rendered with the new values! Please have a look at the fallowing code:

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>eisenhower</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> eisenhower}}
</body>

<template name="eisenhower">
    <div class="eisenhower">

        <select id="assortment"> <!-- HERE IS THE DROPDOWN LIST -->
            <option value="">all tasks</option>
            <option value="true">done tasks</option>
            <option value="false" selected>undone tasks</option>
        </select>

        <div>
            <h1>{{doTasksCount}} to do</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><form><input type="input" name="new" section="do" /></form></li>
                {{#each doTasks}}
                    <li><input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" /> {{task}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>{{scheduleTasksCount}} to schedule</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><form><input type="input" name="new" section="schedule" /></form></li>
                {{#each scheduleTasks}}
                    <li><input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" /> {{task}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>{{delegateTasksCount}} to delegate</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><form><input type="input" name="new" section="delegate" /></form></li>
                {{#each delegateTasks}}
                    <li><input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" /> {{task}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>{{abandonTasksCount}} to abandon</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><form><input type="input" name="new" section="abandon" /></form></li>
                {{#each abandonTasks}}
                    <li><input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" /> {{task}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
assortment = true; // HERE IS MY VARIABLE FOR CHANGING THE .find() CLAUSE!

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.eisenhower.helpers({
        //tasks
        doTasks: function() {
            return Tasks.find({section: "do", done: assortment}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        },
        scheduleTasks: function() {
            return Tasks.find({section: "schedule", done: assortment}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        },
        delegateTasks: function() {
            return Tasks.find({section: "delegate", done: assortment}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        },
        abandonTasks:  function() {
            return Tasks.find({section: "abandon", done: assortment}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        },

        checked: function() {
            return Tasks.findOne(this._id).done;
        },

        //tasks counter
        //doTasksCount:         function() { return dos.count(); },
        //scheduleTasksCount: function() { return schedules.count(); },
        //delegateTasksCount: function() { return delegates.count(); },
        //abandonTasksCount:  function() { return abandons.count(); },
    });

    Template.eisenhower.events({
        "submit form": function(event, template) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var obj     = event.target.new; //input reference
            var task    = obj.value;
            var section = obj.getAttribute("section"); //obj.section doesnt work here

            Tasks.insert({task: task, section: section, done: false, createdAt: new Date()}, function(error, id) {
                if(!error) {
                    event.target.new.value = ""; //clear form
                }
            });
        },

        "change checkbox": function(event) {
            Tasks.update(this._id, {$set: {done: event.target.checked}});
        },

        "change select": function(event) {
            assortment = (event.target.value) ? event.target.value : true; // SET VARIABLE! BUT DATA DOESNT CHANGE THOUGH!?
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to get this working is to change the `assortment` variable to a reactive data source.  When a reactive data source is reset in Meteor, the functions depending on it are rerun.  When a plain vanilla variable is reset, functions are not rerun.

Your two options here are to make `assortment` a `Session` key, or to make it a `ReactiveVar`.  You should take a look at the documentation for each and choose the one that fits best for you:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar

There are some noteworthy differences between the two, e.g., `ReactiveVar` requires a package to be installed and will not rerun when the value is reset to the same value as existed previously. But to demonstrate the pattern with `Session`, you will want to set it initially:

`Session.setDefault('assortment', true);`

In your template helpers, get the value:

```
doTasks: function() {
  return Tasks.find({section: "do", done: Session.get('assortment')}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
}
```

And set it in your template event:

```
"change select": function(event) {
  var assortment = (event.target.value) ? event.target.value : true;
  Session.set('assortment', assortment);
}
```

Comment: Can you check your browser's console with 'Session.get("assortment")' to see if the Session value is being reset on "change select"?

Comment: Nice catch! - Thank you very much! I've learned a lot!

At the end it was the reactive variable issue and a problem with the returned value from the <select> field, because it was returned as a string and I saved booleans inside my mongo document!